# Is there any way to switch off Auto Register Feature so that it ignores any dll files in the same folder?

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I have 4 files: Launcher.exe, Application.exe, Nlog.dll and Nlog.Windows.Forms.dll.

Launcher.exe is used to update Application.exe and the Nlog files so Launcher.exe has is own merged copy of Nlog.dll. If I delete Nlog.Windows.Forms.dll is removed from the folder it all works perfectly and Nlog.dll in the main folder can be updated as it is not in use.

If NLog.Windows.Forms.dll is in the same folder, Nlog.dll cannot be updated. I believe this is because NLog is Auto Detecting the Windows Forms dll which in turn locks Nlog.dll and Nlog.Windows.Forms.dll which i do not want!

Is there a way to stop this? Can I disable the autodetection? I do not use a config file, i build my config in code:

```
 Dim test As New NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration
 Dim logToFile As New NLog.Targets.NullTarget("MyApp")
 test.AddRuleForAllLevels(logToFile)
 NLog.LogManager.Configuration = test
 MyApp.nLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Julian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating the first NLog Logger (GetLogger / GetCurrentClassLogger) or assigning LogManager.Configuration, then you can do this:

```
   Dim configFactory As New NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory(GetType(NLog.ILogger).Assembly)
   NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.[Default] = configFactory 

   Dim test As New NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration
   Dim logToFile As New NLog.Targets.NullTarget("MyApp")
   NLog.LogManager.Configuration = test
   MyApp.nLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
```

Please forgive me for the possible broken VB.NET syntax.

Comment: Thanks @rolf that is perfect! How does this work exactly? I had figured out i needed to do something before loading the configuration but I wouldnt have worked that out!

Comment: It will skip the default assembly auto-loading logic, when assigning your own "custom" ConfigurationItemFactory. The factory constructor takes an array of assemblies to scan for config-items (targets, layouts, etc.). But here I just give the NLog-assembly.

Comment: Ah ok excellent, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. It makes sense now!